# Double pointer in c, assignment warning for my code

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, double-pointer

I don't know why I am getting warnings for the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{
    int **p;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
            p=(int*)malloc(1*sizeof(int));
        else
            p=(int*)realloc(p,(i+1)*sizeof(int));
        p[i]=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));

        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
           p[i][j]=j;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
            printf("%5d",p[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any other way to allocate memory dynamically for a double pointer.

Comment: Can you show the warning messages?

Comment: @Sashank, what are you trying to do with this code?

Comment: why are you using dynamic allocation of `p` to begin with?  Why not `int *p[5];`?

Comment: @EricZ I am trying to implement a demo program by inserting values into 2d array which is created by allocating memory dynamically.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I am trying to use double pointer, why double pointer because the fragment in which you specified int *p[5] you have to specify a value i.e, the number of rows , what if you don't know how many rows you are going to create.

Comment: @SashankAlladi: Well, `5` was hard-coded in your program, so I thought you knew it in advance.  If you don't know until after a few iterations, then I agree.

Comment: @BenVoigt I got you, The program is just a demo, well its my fault I have to explicitly specify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This compiles with no warning

```
  int **p;
  p = (int **) malloc(sizeof(void *));
```

Comment: What compiler will return a different size for a void* than an int**?

Comment: Those examples are C++

Comment: So?  C++ provides the same guarantees on primitive types as C.  It's the platform, not the language, that determines pointer sizes.  (You're welcome to pull a rule out of the C standard that says otherwise... but I don't think any exists)

Comment: Just checked the C standard.  Section 6.2.5/26 is the relevant rule, and explicitly says that `void*` doesn't have to be the same size as any other pointer except `char*`.

Comment: malloc returns an untyped void * and you cast it to the pointer type that you want.  How would that work with different pointer sizes?

Comment: Try actually reading the explanations I linked to.  Short version: `void*` needs to be able to contain any address, `int*` only needs to be able to contain aligned addresses, which means less information.

Comment: Since you've been given ample opportunity to correct your answer but persist in spreading wrong code, you've earned a -1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

You get warnings because p is an `int **` and you are allocating memory as if it was an `int *` in your `if..else` lines. Simply replace your lines as follows:

```
p=(int **)malloc(1*sizeof(int *));

p=(int **)realloc(p,(i+1)*sizeof(int *));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting warnings because you're (a) casting the return value of `malloc()` and `realloc()`, and (b) casting it to the *wrong type*. In C it's generally considered best not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and `realloc()` at all, because `void*` will automatically convert to any other pointer type, and putting in the unnecessary cast can lead to errors (such as yours, for example).